# how to access the UITabBarController when its not the initial view?

Tags: objective-c, ios5, storyboard

I'm having problem with accessing my tabbarcontroller in the storyboard when its not the initial view. So basically there is an initial view in the storyboard which leads to the tabbarcontroller. I want to change the color of the tab but i dont have access to it! I know that it can be added to the delegate if its the initial view but in this case its not the initial view in the storyboard! I read somewhere that I have to override a method in the first view but there was no detail about it!

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a viewcontroller in the storyboard then this code:
UIStoryboard *storyboard = self.storyboard;
    UIViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"OtherViewController"];

Will get the other viewcontroller youw want and you could do things such as:
set yourself as delegate for it:
    [(OtherViewController *)vc setDelegate:self];
display it:
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];

I think you could use this to get the other viewcontroller and then access the tabbar from it.

Sorry if I misunderstood what you are trying to do.